# How to display options in collection_select from controller rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a scenario where upon selecting a `designation`, `benefits` will load in a drop down according to that `designation`.
I have written an ajax call for this.

**HTML:**

```
<label>Designations</label>
<%= f.association :designation, input_html: { id: 'designation_select'},label_html: { class: 'form-control-plaintext' } %>

<label>Benefits</label>
<%= f.collection_select :benefit_ids, Benefit.all,:id, :name, {}, { id: 'benefit_select',multiple: 'multiple', :class => 'form-control multiselect-all',:include_blank => "Select Benefit" } %>
```

**AJAX call:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {

    $('#designation_select').change(function() {
      debugger
      id = $('#designation_select')[0].value;
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {designation_id: id},
          url: '/benefits/benefit_by_designation',
          success: function(result) {
            debugger
            var el, length, options, parser, results, x;
            $('#benefit_select').empty();
            $('#benefit_select').prepend('<option value=\'\'> Select Benefit </option>');
            parser = new DOMParser;
            el = parser.parseFromString(result, 'text/html');
            options = el.getElementsByTagName('option');
            length = options.length;
            x = 0;
            results = [];
            while (x < length) {
              $('#designation_select')[0].appendChild(options[0]);
              results.push(x++);
            }
            return results;
          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Method in **Controller**:

```
  def benefit_by_designation
    benefits = Benefit.where('designation_id = ?', params[:designation_id])
    render html: view_context.options_from_collection_for_select(benefits, :id, :name, {include_blank: 'Select Benefit'})
  end
```

The code is running perfectly fine uptil the `benefits = Benefit.where..` query in controller, but the `render html:` is not working as I wished it to. How to display that `benefits` list in the dropdown?

**EDIT:**
I had accidentaly set the `datatype` in ajax call as`json` but I have now set it to `html`. Now, the success case of ajax call is being hit but still no results displayed.

Comment: If you're using ajax, wouldn't you also need respond_to :js ?

Comment: I have no idea, you tell me..

Answer (score 1):

try

```
def benefit_by_designation
 benefits = Benefit.where('designation_id = ?', params[:designation_id])
 render json: {:benefits => benefits }
end
```

change your ajax success as

```
success: function(result) {
         var options='';
          options += '<option value=\'\'> Select Benefit </option>';
          if(result.benefits)
            $.each(result.benefits,function(key, val){
              options += '<option value="'+val['id']+'">'+val['name']+'</option>';
            });
          var option_set = $('#benefit_select').html(options);
          option_set.trigger('change');
        }
```

hope this will help..

Comment: Didnt work. Although the console didnt log any errors but the results werent displayed on the page either :(

Comment: can u console the result.benefits in success method, `console.log(result.benefits)` and look what output got

Comment: It shows the 2 options that should have appeared in the dropdown in success case `0: {id: 72, name: "Car Insurance", created_at: "2019-07-19T10:38:30.305Z", updated_at: "2019-07-19T10:38:30.305Z", designation_id: 1, …}`
`1: {id: 73, name: "Health insurance", created_at: "2019-07-19T10:38:39.594Z", updated_at: "2019-07-19T10:38:39.594Z", designation_id: 1, …}`

Comment: change your select to this `<%= f.select :benefit_ids, Benefit.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:prompt=>""}, { :multiple => false, :size => 0 ,:class=> "form-control multiselect-all", :id=> "benefit_select" } %>`